# Will installing full text search on live SQL server 2008r2 database server cause downtime?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, full-text-search

Will adding the SQL full text component an existing live SQL Server 2008R2 Database Server cause the server to be restarted/reset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it will not cause any downtime, its a feature and you can simply install it and start using it.

You do not need to restart your server at all. Just make sure once you have installed Full-Text Search , it is running (FTS Windows Service).